# How do we clip the derived variables so that values of trainable values are also clipped accordingly

Tags: tensorflow

When I create a variable (not used in calculating predicted output) that is being derived from the trainable variables and apply a clip-on that, are the actual trainable variables also getting clipped according to the values that the derived variables can take or not? If not, is there a way to do that.

If you take a simple linear regression example for the ease of explanation:

Y = Ax + B (where A and B are the trainable variables and x is our input)

if we create a variable:

```
C = tf.Variable(B/A, dtype ='float64')
```

and apply a clip on C:

```
C = tf.clip_by_value(C, c_min, c_max)
```

And now optimize the mean_square_error of the predicted Y and actual Y on a set of inputs, will we get B and A such that it satisfies values that C can take? 
If not, is there a way to do that?

In my case I have complex derived variables whose ratio of sums are to be clipped but if I have the answer to the above problem I think I will have the foundation and will be able to build on that.